# Disabling linked text within a linked, disjointed rollver-swap div

Tags: javascript, css, html

I have created a small div rectangle "button" which is contained within block-level a tags, thus making the entire div a rollover link which, via eventhandlers and javascript, swaps two images on the page. I would like to put some text within this div, to identify the rollover button. However, since it is inside the "a" tag all text inside the div is immediately styled as link text. I can style/disable the psuedoclass of the link, no problem.

The question is: how do I make the eventhandler in the div *not* fire when hovering on the text within the div? Right now, it fires twice: once when you move the cursor into the div, and again when you hover over the text. I would like the text to be ignored or "flattened" into the background...

This may be easiest to accomplish the old-fashioned way, with a button graphic. I was hoping to do it with only CSS.

The CSS:

```
a.notunderlined  {text-decoration:none; display:block;}

#compbutton  {position:relative; text-align:center; 
width:154px; height:31px; background:black;}

p6  {position:relative; font-family:open_sansregular; font-size:9pt; 
letter-spacing:1px; color:white; top:5px;}
```

The Markup:

```
<a class="notunderlined" href="composition.html">

<div id="compbutton" onMouseOver="MM_swapImage('mainpic','',
   'images/anigifs/ear8.gif',1)" onMouseOut="MM_swapImgRestore()">
    <p6>composition</p6>
</div>

</a>
```

I tried adding an empty div ("csstext") instead of the p6 tag above and adding the word  ('composition') via CSS like so:

```
#csstext:before  {content:"composition";}
```

Interestingly, adding the word to the div via CSS created an invisible horizontal line across the entire div at the baseline of the text. Moving the cursor across that line anywhere in the div triggers the eventhandler to fire the swap. If anyone can explain *that*...I would love to hear it.

Thanks people....!

Comment: onMouseOver is the old fashioned way. Look up CSS `:hover`

Comment: popnoodles...pardon my ignorance. As I've said I am very familiar with styling the psuedoclasses and hence CSS :hover  Unless I am missing something, styling in this fashion will not prevent the eventhandler (onmouseover) from firing both in the div and when hovering over text inside the div.